# Putting a navigation controller with hierarchical table views inside of a view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, navigationcontroller

I am making an iPad application which requires the use of a "drill down" style set of table views for users to add elements to a list (i.e. a user taps on a table view cell and it brings up more detail or options, like you would see in settings). My problem is that I need to be able to place this table view inside of a view controller amongst other content. I can add a table view, but I need the navigation bar at the top of the view in order to mimic a tableView inside of a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `UIViewController` and

- give it a `tableView` property
- make it conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol
- make it conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol

Navigation controller works exactly the same way regardless if you use a `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`. Create storyboard segues and inform the detail view about the object to be displayed in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Just one question, how can I position this table view controller on the screen? Also I have to do this programatically :(

Comment: You should use interface builder and connect the `tableView` to an `@IBOutlet`. Use auto-layout constraints to position the table view. - Do not do this in code.